# How deploy spring application in app engine larger than 35mb

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-app-engine, spring-boot

I try mvn appengine:deploy but receive

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cannot upload file [my-file], which has size [40375610] 
(greater than maximum allowed size of [33554432]). Please delete the file or add to the skip_files entry in your application .yaml file and try again.

I know app engine deploy support file up until 35mb but i dont know how deploy files large more 35mb

Comment: Out of curiosity - what is in that 40M file?

Comment: @Dan Cornilescu:  Stanford Core NLP jar dependency is almost 400MB. There are a lot big jar libs out there.

Comment: You solved this error?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that 35M is not all Java code!  I suspect you have a lot of static files.  If so, you can upload these to [GCloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) and server them from there instead.

Comment: I have something similar to this. I have a file (which is a huge chunk) of nearly 1gb and a flask app. So I am basically trying to deploy it on app engine but since flask app reads the huge file, i need that to be deployed as well, but it gives me an error of maimum file size reached. I figured something similar but would like to have more light thrown on that. If you can help? @BareNakedCoder

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if  you really want to stick with Standard Environment. (You probably do if your application doesn't need to be running 100% of the time). However App Engine Flex allows you to deploy really big jar. As far as I know a fat jar of size over 400MB is deployable.