# Upload big jar file to Google Cloud Appengine

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-app-engine

so I am trying to deploy my spring-based application to Google Appengine via Maven plugin. I am getting error, that my jar is bigger then allowed size.

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cannot upload file 
[C:\path\core-web\target\appengine-
staging\core-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar], which has size [54043570] (greater 
than maximum allowed size of [33554432]). Please delete the file or add to 
the skip_files entry in your application .yaml file and try again.
```

My pom-where I am trying to run mvn appengine:deploy is:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And my app.yaml looks like this:

```
runtime: java
env: standard

runtime_config:  # Optional
  jdk: openjdk8

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored

resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2.3
  disk_size_gb: 10
  volumes:
  - name: ramdisk1
    volume_type: tmpfs
    size_gb: 0.5

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

I used to run my application with exact same setup (only on flexible environment) and uploading proceeded correctly.

Thanks for help.

EDIT: I tried using jarSplitting property in plugin configuration but jar wasn't splitted for any configuration I used.

Comment: Seems quite similar to the discussion in here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45579638/how-deploy-spring-application-in-app-engine-larger-than-35mb

Comment: Yea, saw that, unfurtunately most size are external libraries that are in spring boot.

Comment: You solved this error?

Comment: Nope, I always failed with this approach (directly deploy Jar file), kinda everywhere (Azure, AWS, GCD). From that time, I always just create my environment (using docker) and deploy the container, which works like a charm. Saved me a lot of time from that time.