# greater than maximum allowed size of [33554432] in Google cloud platform

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When deploying spring-boot app on GCP, the following error has been displayed.

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cannot upload file
>   [/home/info/Project1/target/appengine-staging/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar],
>   which has size [42865605] (greater than maximum allowed size of
>   [33554432]). Please delete the file or add to the skip_files entry in
>   your application .yaml file and try again.

pom.xml as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>myproject</name>
    <description>aaaaaa</description>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>    

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.9.0</jjwt.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Working with Json Web Tokens (JWT) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Java 8 Date/Time Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.0</version>
              <configuration>
                <webResources>
                  <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                  <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                  </resource>
                </webResources>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
            </plugin>
        <!-- add appengine-maven-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <deploy.promote>true</deploy.promote>
                    <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

I already removed static file,but still jar file was not reduced.
Anybody please let me know how to reduced jar file size?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45579638/4495081

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google App Engine has a quota limit of 32 MB (for `GO` 64 MB) per file in your deployment.

Since you are using Java your SNAPSHOT.jar (at 40.8 MB) exceeds the limit of 32 MB.

This limit applies to both standard and flex environments.

[App Engine Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas)

Comment: How do I go for 64MB ? I cannot find such configuration in Appengine.

Comment: The quotas page lists Go applications supporting 64 MB. However, everywhere else in the documentation the limit is 32 MB. For Java, you are limited to 32 MB. Either reduce the size of your jars or switch to Compute Engine.

Comment: When you say `How do I go for 64MB?`. I am referring to the language `GO`.

Comment: Since the app is spring-boot, I am unable to use GO. Can you suggest any other Engine that suits for my requirement(jar size>42GB)?

Comment: I did,` Compute Engine`. App Engine has limits that you are exceeding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try on Compute Engine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to run

```
mvn clean package
```

before deploy, and maybe you have to update your gcloud SDK

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have following setting enabled in your app's appengine-web.xml/app.yaml or pom.xml

```
 <staging>
  <enable-jar-classes>true</enable-jar-classes>
  </staging>
```

It tries to bundle all classes into one jar which might exceed the limit imposed by GCP.
Relaxing this setting, can allow your deployment though bit slow now.

Alternatively, you can choose to deploy via Eclipse GUI:

**Project Explorer >> Right click on root node >> Deploy to App Engine Standard.**

This takes care of permissible bundling of the jars if setting is enabled and makes sure the package does get deployed.